# How to trigger a Google Cloud Composer DAG based on a latest record in the control table

Tags: triggers, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG thet loads the data into no of raw tables .There is a control table that stores the list of tables and when they are last updated by the DAG .This is all managed by different ta=eam.  I am trying to create a DAG to run a query on one of the raw table and load it into persistant table. I would like to run the DAG as soon as i see the latest time stamp  than what i  already processed in my control table.
I am new to the Cloud Composer, can you please let me know how i can accomplish it?

Thanks